# How to configure squid to accept all http headers

Tags: proxy, squid

I'm trying to connect to my SSH server through squid using HTTP injector but I get a protocol mismatch. The problem is only with the following payload I guess as it has a `\n` before GET. Using some other public squid proxies though, everything works fine and I can connect to my SSH server. 
I allowed CONNECT from `squid.conf` and all `http_access`. Is there anything else that could fix the problem?

```
CONNECT myserver:22@site.com HTTP/1.0\r\n[delay_split]\nGET http://site.com/ HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: site.com\r\n\r\n
```